# Tweaking iCarousel to be stacked card view

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, icarousel

I need to achieve a stacked card view 100% similar to the [JZStackedView](https://github.com/zammitjames/JZStackedView)

It looks like this and is a very neat setup:

[image]

What I have achieved so far with iCarousel is a little bit disappointing and it just doesn't work.

Here are all my values

```
_mainCarousel.vertical = YES;
_mainCarousel.type = iCarouselTypeTimeMachine;
_mainCarousel.viewpointOffset = CGSizeMake(0,5);
_mainCarousel.perspective = -0.31;
```

And the following method

```
- (CGFloat)carousel:(__unused iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value{
    switch (option)
    {
        case iCarouselOptionWrap:
        {
            return YES;
        }
        case iCarouselOptionSpacing:
        {
            return value * 0.0003f;
        }
        case iCarouselOptionFadeMax:
        {
            return value;
        }
        case iCarouselOptionTilt:
        {
            return 0.05f;
        }
        case iCarouselOptionVisibleItems:
        {
            return 3;
        }
    }
}
```

Would anyone mind pointing me in the right direction?

I'm not using JZStackedView because it's a little bit laggy and doesn't have infinite scrolling. I wouldn't also want to implement it with `UICollectionView` because I really like the speed and the flexibility of `iCarousel`.

Comment: did you solved your problem ? and anyone having this in swift ?